# What is the significance or use for the engagement ring quest item?

Tags: prey

When rummaging through every cabinet or box or container in Prey (2017), one of the items I've found was an engagement ring. This is marked as a Quest Item (grey backgroung) in my inventory and I cannot recycle it, yet I found no quest relating to it (while there are quests relating to some other items I may have found by accident).

Did I miss some quest relating to this ring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.polygon.com/prey-guide-walkthrough/2017/5/23/15679592/with-this-ring-optional-objective-kevin-nicole-hague-wedding-ring-cargo-bay-executive-suites, this is an objective for a quest you get in the Cargo Bay area.

Comment: It should be noted that you can only start this quest before you secure the Cargo Bay area. Afterwards, the NPC will just comment on your actions, but won't give you the quest anymore.